# get image from a linux server and display it on website

Tags: html

i have an image on a linux server somewhere and a website on another server. i need a way for the website to directly access this image. Is there a way?

Comment: yes both the servers are linux servers. i need to display an image on server 1 to server 2 where the website is located. is there a way to do it without copying the image? as there are many website servers and i dont want to copy the image to wach of the servers. code snippets is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can share the directory you're interested in from the linux server to your web server.

You can use `NFS` if both servers are Unix-type machines, or use `Samba` if the web part is running on Windows.

For more information, look at the  [Linux NFS HowTo](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get public access to the linux web server, it's surely possible.

In short, you can add any accessible image to an HTML document, irrespective of it's location.

Comment: i just need to know how to insert the image url in the one of the htmls of the webserver.. like url(www.abc.com/images/myimage.png)

Comment: is it like url(webserver1/home/user/image.png)?

Comment: simply assign the URL of the image to the src attribute of img tag.

Comment: what do u mean by url?? can you please give me a code snippet?

Comment: @gunner: i'm guessing what you mean is point the `href` or `src` elements or whatever to the Linux server. This only works if the linux machine is a. publicly visible and b. _also has a webserver_.

Comment: @Mat: Yes, that's what I meant and I also wrote that explicitly in the answer.

Comment: @gunner, you didn't say anything about it requiring a web server on the linux host.

Comment: @Mat: I mentioned about public access, but forgot to add about the webs server. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

is the webserver also a linux machine?

probably you can copy the image using ssh to your server every minute with a cronjob.

or trigger a rsync every minute.

some more information about your machines would be usefull